# Flutter, DateTime.now() is not working in my code

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been developing an application for both iOS and Android.

The code below makes real-time screen which shows current time.

1.I confirmed that `DateTime.now()` is working on both OS.

2.Also i confirmed that it is working at the actual Android device and Android emulator.

But everytime when i am trying to test on iOS(both emulator and actual device), `_timeString` always get a `null`.

What is wrong with this code? I don't get it.

Here is my environment in advance for solving my question.

VMware workstation 15 Player, Xcode 10.3, Android Studio 3.4.2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}

class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {
  String _timeString;

  String _formatDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timeString = _formatDateTime(DateTime.now()); 
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (Timer t) => _getTime()); 
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getTime() {
    DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
    final String formattedDateTime = _formatDateTime(_now);
    if (this.mounted) { 
      setState(() {
        _timeString = formattedDateTime; 
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Scaffold(
          body:
          Container(
              child:
              Text("\n\n\n\n${_timeString}")
          )
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by changing date format

To

MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: It is not working. As far as i know, the difference between ```hh``` and ```HH``` is expression of hours(12hrs or 24hrs). Is there any function except for this?

Comment: So first check that DateTime.now() return something or null.?

Comment: DateTime.now() returns correct time. The problem is when i am trying to receive time in real time by using ```initState()``` or ```_getTime()```(i am not sure which one is not working on iOS), i got ```null```.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code without any change. (Added a entry point however) 
and it works as expected.

Any additional information regarding the `intl` package will be helpful. Here is my entire app and the result of that below.
My dependency is `intl: ^0.15.8`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(SampleApp());
}

class SampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample App',
      home: TableLayout(),
    );
  }
}


class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}

class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {
  String _timeString;

  String _formatDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timeString = _formatDateTime(DateTime.now());
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (Timer t) => _getTime());
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getTime() {
    DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
    final String formattedDateTime = _formatDateTime(_now);
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _timeString = formattedDateTime;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Scaffold(
          body:
          Container(
              child:
              Text("\n\n\n\n${_timeString}")
          )
      );
  }
}
```

[App running on IOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxvT8.png)

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but it returns ```null``` again..even i have a same version of intl with you..

Comment: Can you provide any form of logs to debug? and also most importantly, Is your flutter version updated to 1.7.8?

Comment: the error was just ```except was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.```. Anyway is it okay if i use ```Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TableLayout()));``` from other screen rather than using ```SampleApp()```?

Comment: Hey @m0f1us no offense sir but it is a good practice to paste the stack or provide complete information about the error. In your case, is it saying NoSuchMethodError on DateFormat() method or any other place? Also, I this PageRoute is ok, I just added a entry point to start the application. Let me know where the error hits so it can be debugged further!